# Openshift cmd only get events of last 5 Minutes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Is there an `oc` or `kubectl` command that prints out only events of the last 5 Minutes?

Something like:

```
oc get events --last="5-Minutes"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events for  the last 5 Minutes or N mins is currently an Open issue you can follow this [github link](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1440) for more feature enhancements. You can also raise a comment under this link or else you can raise a new feature request .
We can also use the below commands as of now :

1. This command gives all the events with the time stamp. Refer to this [doc](https://linuxhint.com/sort-kubectl-events-by-time/)

   `$ kubectl get events --sort-by='.metadata.creationTimestamp' -A`
2. To sort out the events by the last seen timestamp, execute the following cited command in the shell:

   `$ kubectl get events --sort-by=’.lastTimestamp’`
3. Adding --output-watch-events=true gives the [deleted Events](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/704#issuecomment-1037509515) also :

   `$ kubectl get events -n my-namespace --output-watch-events=true --watch-only`